# Inno Setup Compiler "Could not call proc" Error

Tags: video, background, inno-setup

I am about to finalize my Inno Setup Script but I even can't because after compiling the script , I was getting "Could not call proc" Error when choosing to play Background Video during program installation.After I click "OK" on the exception message box appears , the video plays fine and automatically closing when setup completed as I expected.
Why "Could not call proc" error happens when I choose "Video Background" radio button and then clicking on "Install"?

A red line is showing the line 515.
The line 515 is:

```
if DSInitializeVideoFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Video.mp4'), BackgroundForm.Handle, Width, Height, @BackgroundVideoPlay) then
```

The procedure () PlayMPEGVideo is being called by the Installation page ONLY WHEN CHOOSE TO PLAY VIDEO AS THE BACKGROUND.

I pasted the whole Script in Pastebin because the whole code is needed to find where the execution order problem that causes "Could not call proc"................
LINK : http://pastebin.com/MaFNeCTZ

Thanks in advance.

THE REDUCED SCRIPT:

```
procedure PlayMPEGVideo();
var
  Width, Height: Integer;
begin
if VBRadio2.Checked then begin
if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Video.mp4')) then begin
if DSInitializeVideoFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Video.mp4'),BackgroundForm.Handle, Width, Height, @BackgroundVideoPlay) then
begin
  BackgroundForm.Width := GetSystemMetrics(0);
  BackgroundForm.Height := GetSystemMetrics(1);
  DSPlayMediaFile;
  WizardForm.BringToFront;
  PauseBT.Show;
  PlayBT1.hide;
  PlayBT.hide;
with WizardForm do begin
WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := 'Install';
end;
end;
end;
end else begin
with WizardForm do begin
if CurPageID=wpInstalling then begin
  PauseBT.hide;
  CompactCheckBox.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Show;
  WizardForm.Bevel1.Show;
  //WizardForm.Caption := '                                        Installing Grand Theft  Auto IV';
  with WizardForm do begin
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.show;
     end;
    end;
   end;
  end;
 end;
```

If you cant' find an error which may cause "Could not call proc" error , then you might need to view the whole script from the given link.

HERE IT IS:

```
  type
  TDirectShowEventProc = procedure(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer);

  function DSGetLastError(var ErrorText: WideString): HRESULT;
  external 'DSGetLastError@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
  function DSPlayMediaFile: Boolean;
  external 'DSPlayMediaFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
  function DSStopMediaPlay: Boolean;
  external 'DSStopMediaPlay@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
  function DSSetVolume(Value: LongInt): Boolean;
  external 'DSSetVolume@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
  function DSSetBalance(Value: LongInt): Boolean;
  external 'DSSetBalance@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
  function DSInitializeAudioFile(FileName: WideString; CallbackProc: TDirectShowEventProc): Boolean;
  external 'DSInitializeAudioFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
  function DSInitializeVideoFile(FileName: WideString; WindowHandle: HWND; var Width, Height: Integer; CallbackProc: TDirectShowEventProc): Boolean;
  external 'DSInitializeVideoFile@files:mediaplayer.dll stdcall';
```

UPDATED NOW.

Comment: That's why I can't reduce the script.If I reduce , more than half of the script even need to be re-posted.I posted the whole script in the pastebin address.I like to know why you don't like to look it through the link I given...............If you look it , you will understand that I told the truth.

Comment: Martin I tried more than two hours and found the error which caused the "Could not call proc".The error caused because the WizardPage to play the video id not defined.I defined it with CurPageID  and everything seems fine.Thanks for giving me some enthusiasm.